# Bash testing -n

Tags: bash, if-statement, testing, quoting

I thought the `-z` option in a bash test would be true if the condition evaluates to null and `-n` would be true if the condition is *not* null. So then why is this happening?

```
var1=
echo ${#var1} # 0

[ -n $var1 ] && echo 'hi' # hi
unset var1
[ -n $var1 ] && echo 'hi' # still prints hi!
```

Comment: relevant info https://serverfault.com/a/382740

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#STRTEST